# FInd and copy multiple files that contain a pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ubuntu, terminal

When I need to copy multiple files in the same dir I can just:

- cp *file{20..30}* newLocation

But when I combine that with find, it doesn't work.

- find . -name '*file{20..30}*' -exec cp '{}' newLocation ';'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `{20..30}` range syntax is a special feature of Bash's command-line parser.  It is not part of standard POSIX globbing, such as `find`'s `-name` test performs, and it's not even recognized by Bash in some contexts where you might like it to be.

You already know the simpler, more direct alternative that I would otherwise recommend for your example case.  You could also do something like

```
find . '(' -name 'file2[0-9]' -o -name file30 ')' -exec cp '{}' newLocation ';'
```

, though that doesn't work very well if the endpoints of the range are determined dynamically.

If the point of using `find` is to avoid problems arising from some of the files not existing, then you might consider addressing it like this:

```
for f in file{20..30}; do
    [[ -e "$f" ]] && cp "$f" newLocation
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from the other post/answer, enclosing the names with a `(` and closing `)` plus the `-o` and `-name` in between.

Something like this should be able to add those strings from your input file/string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

format() {
  local f
  declare -ag files
  for f; do
    files+=( -o -name "$f" )
  done
}

format file{10..20}
```

---

Now check the value of `"${files[@]}"`

```
declare -p files
```

Output

```
declare -a files=([0]="-o" [1]="-name" [2]="file10" [3]="-o" [4]="-name" [5]="file11" [6]="-o" [7]="-name" [8]="file12" [9]="-o" [10]="-name" [11]="file13" [12]="-o" [13]="-name" [14]="file14" [15]="-o" [16]="-name" [17]="file15" [18]="-o" [19]="-name" [20]="file16" [21]="-o" [22]="-name" [23]="file17" [24]="-o" [25]="-name" [26]="file18" [27]="-o" [28]="-name" [29]="file19" [30]="-o" [31]="-name" [32]="file20")
```

---

To see what would it look like when used as an input to `find`

```
printf '%s\n' "\( ${files[*]} \)"
```

Output

```
\( -o -name file10 -o -name file11 -o -name file12 -o -name file13 -o -name file14 -o -name file15 -o -name file16 -o -name file17 -o -name file18 -o -name file19 -o -name file20 \)
```

To use that array `files` as an input to `find`

```
find . -type f \( "${files[@]:1}" \) -exec bash -c 'echo cp -v -- "$@" /destination' _ {} +
```

- The `"${files[@]:1}"` removes the leading `-o`
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output so files copying should occur.

---

Or just use `globstar` with `nullglob`'

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob

cp -v ./**/file{10..20} /destination
```

---

The leading `./` means the current directory, It could be

```
/path/to/source/**/file{10..20}
```

where `/path/to/source/` is the directory where the files in question are.